# Use values from the df2 where row value matches df1 column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like these:

df1:

```
id  |  2019-03-01 |  2019-04-01 | 2019-05-01 | sum   
id1 |    42       |    69       | 96         | 868  
id2 |    15       |    21       | 76         | 321  
id3 |    34       |    45       | 35         | 675
```

df2:

```
id  |  month| avail   
id1 |    3  | 10  
id2 |    4  | 54  
id2 |    5  | 34  
id3 |    5  | 33
```

I need to add  value from **avail** column at every column where **df2.month == df.columns.values[n].month** and if theres no corresponding record =>add 0

This was my attempt with np.where but I did not succeed:

```
df1.columns.values[:-1] = pd.to_datetime(df1.columns.values[:-1])  
for c in np.arange(start = 0, stop = len(df1.columns[:-1]), step = 1):  
    df1['h'+str(c+1)] = df1.iloc[: , -1].add(np.where((df2.id.isin(df1.index))& 
                                             (df1.columns.values[c].month == df2.month), 
                                             df2.avail, 0)).sub(df1.iloc[:, c])
df1 = df1.filter(like = 'h').reset_index()
```

The expected output is:

```
id  |  h1 |  h2 | h3    
id1 |  836| 767 | 671 
id2 |  306| 339 | 297  
id3 |  641| 596 | 594
```

Comment: Pleas share the expected output

Comment: @yatu added, pls check

Comment: Can you add more explanations on how you get the output ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. Last column of the df1 + conditional addition of avail from df2 (the part I have problems with) - from 1 to 3rd column of df1 depending on iteration step. Then filtering by 'h' so that only h1...hN columns remained

Comment: @Ison how did you get the value for id2-h2? should the value be 354 from 321-21+54?

Comment: @Ben.T at the second iteration, when we compute the h2, the last column of df1 becomes h1

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like with `set_index` and `unstack` on df2, `set_index` and `drop` on df1, then `cumsum` the difference between both result over the column, then add the column sum once reshaped with `[:, None]`, plus some `rename` and `rename_axis`.

```
df_f = (df1['sum'].values[:, None] 
        + (df2.set_index(['id','month'])['avail'].unstack().fillna(0)
           - df1.set_index('id').drop('sum', axis=1)
                .rename(columns=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).month)).cumsum(axis=1))\
       .rename_axis(columns=None)\
       .reset_index()

print (df_f)
        id      3      4      5
0      id1  836.0  767.0  671.0
1      id2  306.0  339.0  297.0
2      id3  641.0  596.0  594.0
```

you may want to rename the column to fit your exact output

Comment: Elegant solution! But when I tried it on data it produced an error: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (5, 5): given (4, 1)

Comment: @Ison what are the initial shape of df1 and df2?

Comment: (4, 6) and (6, 3)

Comment: @Ison do you have an id in df2 not in df1?

Comment: @Ison so try `df1.set_index('id').reindex(index=df2['id'].unique(), fill_value=0)['sum'].values[:, None]` instead of `df1['sum'].values[:, None]` that should do it, but it becomes a bit overkill :p

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work and I still get that error. Nevermind, will think out smth

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach:

```
# sample data
s1 = """id|2019-03-01|2019-04-01|2019-05-01|sum
id1|42|69|96|868
id2|15|21|76|321
id3|34|45|35|675"""
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s1), sep='|')

s2 = """id|month|avail
id1|3|10
id2|4|54
id2|5|34
id3|5|33"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s2), sep='|')
# end sample data

# convert columns to datetime and get the month
new_col = [pd.to_datetime(x).month for x in df1.columns[1:-1]]
df1 = df1.rename(columns=dict(zip(df1.columns[1:-1], new_col)))
# set index
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
# drop the last column
df3 = df1[df1.columns[:-1]]
# pivot df2 so months are the columns
p = df2.pivot('id', 'month', 'avail').fillna(0)
# concat and sum
con = pd.concat([-df3,p]).groupby(level=0).sum()
# add df1['sum'] to the first column
con[con.columns[0]] = con[con.columns[0]] + df1['sum']
# cumsum accross columns
print(con.cumsum(axis=1))

         3      4      5
id                      
id1  836.0  767.0  671.0
id2  306.0  339.0  297.0
id3  641.0  596.0  594.0
```